# Получение и изменение данных Firebase

Tags: база-данных, android-studio, firebase, firebase-database

Являюсь новичком в создании приложений на Android и использованием Firebase. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Имеется вот такая структура БД.
[image: структура]
Необходимо найти конкретный узел по заданному значению id и в нем же поменять значение другого поля. Я пробовал этот код, но он добавляет поля на одном уровне со всеми узлами.

```
        Query query = myRef.orderByChild("id").equalTo(id);
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
               snapshot.getRef().child("isRead").setValue(true);
           }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }

    } );
```

Answer (score 1):

Согласно [официальной документации](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write), это можно сделать вот так:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
mDatabase.child(id).child("isRead").setValue(true);
```

где `id` - это, собственно, переменная с нужным Вам идентификатором.

Внутри `mDatabase.child(id)` Вы можете менять значения любого `child`. Метод `setValue` перезаписывает данные только в указанном месте.